# Constructing a heater by applying power to resistors

Tags: resistors

I need to make a resistor heat up a hot end on my 3D printer separate from my 3D printer control board, mainly because my rep rap is also my CNC mill, which its controls have no way to monitor heat and send voltage to cycle heat. I need it to heat up to at least 280°C and would like to know how to make a circuit to achieve this.

I have tried the following concepts with no luck, a hot glue gun heater element, not hot enough and making a circuit would be my best option just don't have enough knowledge to accomplish that

Comment: You can make a heating element by winding up resistance wire such as nichrome wire. I've never done it. Just read about it online.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a [mica heater?](http://www.minco.com/Heaters/~/media/WWW/Resource%20Library/Minco_HeaterDesignGuide.ashx) What does your printer's "hot end" look like, and what's a "rep rap"?

Comment: temperature sounds just right for a soldering iron. Buy a cheap one and build it in, or buy a spare element for one of the low voltage soldering systems like Weller

Comment: @user44635: Excellent! :-)

Comment: @EMFields "Reprap" is a brand name for a 3D printer

Comment: @EMFields and  "Reprap" is not a brand name for 3d printer it is acronym used in short for self replicating and rapid prototyping.

Comment: @EMFields the pdf file on minco was exactly what i needed thank you for your help i will keep you posted on my process

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to print things, rather than re-invent the wheel from first principles and repeat many of the learning mistakes made in the reprap community over the last several years, you might as well:

- Take one of the already well-proven hot-end heating element & thermistor designs in widespread use and thoroughly published, as their tradeoffs have received substantial practical evaluation.
- Take one of the already well-proven control system designs already in widespread use and thoroughly published as their tradeoffs have received substantial practical evaluation.  Most of these are Arduino derivatives, so in cutting them down to only run the heater you should be able to make do with a simple ATmega and the relevant power MOSFET circuit.

What will be left is coming up with a command interface - either you want to tie this into your G-code interpreter for automatic control, or you will want some sort of manual on/off and setpoint control.  For the latter you could also consider some of the published sous-vide type controllers, at least from the user interface perspective,.

Comment: yes that is what i would like to do is a simple on off from manual control, i have all kinds of Arduino boards and electronic components and have designed the hot end physical properties from one of those already proven all metal ones....do you have simple schematics for or thoughts on the ATmega and power MOSFET circuits?

Comment: The schematics and part selections of many reprap controllers have been published.  If this is something you are prepared to build, you should have no trouble extracting the parts of the circuit which accomplish temperature control of the hot end.

Comment: i do not have a standard 3d printer i have a cnc mill that is 5 axis, i have no control board that is for rep rap i have no way to heat up the hot end to make PLA plasticize..i could probably get the schematics to construct one, my issue is with making a simople piece of metal heat up, i cant find a straight forward answer because i dont know what to look for... i have 2W resistors i have 5w resistors i have heating elements i have voltage regulators, ceramic capacitors a bunch of wire of various guage.... i would like to know how to heat them up safely....

Comment: How many times do I have to say "copy one of the existing proven designs" ?  I know you don't have a complete printer, but extracting the *specific printheader heater and heat controller parts* of one of those **published** designs (especially when most have formal or informal licenses which *encourage* this) and replicating *only* those is going to beat repeating all the mistakes made in the evolution of those designs.

Answer (score 0):

There's two sides to this: physical mechanical construction, and the electrical side. Mechanical construction is going to be full of minor hassles which are offtopic here (expansion of parts, insulating mount, need to crimp rather than solder to nichrome wire, need to mount wire so it doesn't short circuit).

Electrically the obvious solution is nichrome wire. You can get calculator web pages from the manufacturer that will enable you to pick voltage/current/length/heat parameters that are suitable. Temperature is usually given in "free space", if it's inside a mostly-insulated casing it will be hotter.

Then you need some sort of thermostatic control in the power supply. This is where the soldering iron idea shines: it's already assembled and can have temperature control, for less than $100.

If your heater is small enough that you don't need more than about 24V, it's fairly easy to build a PWM-based or even crude on/off thermostatic control system. Higher voltages (especially mains) the safety considerations make it not a beginner project.

Comment: thanks guys the construction part i will be able to accomplish almost immediatly, i own a CNC mill and live tooling CNC lathe i am only struggling on the electrical part i have took into consideration the enclosed space, along with thermal expansion and materials, i like the soldering iron idea i was almost going to do that instead of hot glue gun, my voltage would be around 12V DC from a power supply i like PWM based direction.. i have almost anything at my disposal except ni-chrome wire but i can get some